# Creating a Django model with datetimes from strings

Tags: python, django, datetime

Given the following Django model:

```
from django.db import models

class TimeStamp(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

I was surprised to discover that I can pass in strings instead of `datetime` objects:

```
In [4]: ts = TimeStamp.objects.create(date="2001-12-31")

In [5]: ts.date
Out[5]: '2001-12-31'

In [6]: reloaded_ts = TimeStamp.objects.get(id=ts.id)

In [7]: reloaded_ts.date
Out[7]: datetime.date(2001, 12, 31)
```

Why does Django do this instead of erroring about types? Is there documentation for this behaviour? What time format is it expecting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is expected and documented:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Comment: "A tuple of formats that will be accepted when inputting data on a datetime field" -- ah, so this is a model field, rather than a form field? Why isn't `ts.date` a `datetime`?

Comment: Correct, check out the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield . `ts.date` isn't a `datetime` because you declared it as `DateField`. Try `DateTimeField` and see what happens :)

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Why is `ts.date` a `string` rather than `date`?

Comment: That's a good question. I'd shoot that because you have explicitly created the object with a string date, you'll get this value in return. When fetching from the DB, django cannot tell how did you create the object / which format did you use. Why? Perhaps the devs decided it's more straightforward?

Comment: Ah, found it. It's because `Field.to_python` is only called when the object is written to the database, it doesn't change the attribute on the model. Thanks! :)